# Smallest linux with apt repositories?

Tags: linux, linux-distributions, aptitude, repository, damn-small-linux

Does someone knows a small linux distro that comes with apt package?

I tried puppy linux and dsl, but I didn't like any of those.

I am looking to setup a LAMP into a virtual machine with a small linux, and I am looking for a distro with apt because i am familiar with the package, and it would be easier for me to setup and upgrade a server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a minimal, customised virtual image with `vmbuilder` ([docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/jeos-and-vmbuilder.html)), from the `python-vm-builder` package.

```
sudo vmbuilder kvm ubuntu
```

vmbuilder relies on a very useful debian command, debootstrap.

There is also `virt-install` (`virtinst` package), which can work from an install cd. You can use a netinstall image, [here are debian's](http://www.debian.org/CD/netinst/), [and here is ubuntu's mini.iso](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD). virt-install isn't quite as fast and automated as the python-vm-builder option, I'd only use that to have the option to run the debian-installer or as a fallback for non-debian, non-debootstrap distros.

Comment: thats pretty cool

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntus JeOS was beeing build for exactly your purpose.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JeOS

as single iso until 8.04

Now part of the server iso. Just select "install minimal virtual machine" in the install menu.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [Turnkey LAMP Stack Appliance](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/lamp) fits your needs.

Comment: That looks cool, I will try the ISO cause im using virtualbox.

Comment: I'd upvote 1000 times if I could! Thanks, thanks, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well for light DE you could try lubuntu.

If you just want something light, then use the Ubuntu minimal install and build from there

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at ArchivistaVM, it is only about 100 MByte (with Xorg + Firefox), or 72 MByte without GUI:

http://www.archivista.ch/en/pages/support/download.php

Zip-File without GUI (same password) https://www.archivista.ch/avtest5.zip

It works completely in RAM, startup time is about 15 or 20 seconds, there is a cluster mode (drdb), but at this time, the documentation is not yet fully available in English.

Answer (score 0):

[openSUSE Rescue](http://opensuse.org) is only 591 MB. It comes with the Xfce environment. It does
not come with APT, but does include the similar [zypper tool](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman_Rosetta).